# Sum of specific elements in a list, if they are consecutive (python)

Tags: python, list

> What question is asking for is, from a list of lists like the following, to return a tuple that contains tuples of all occurrences of the number 2 for a given index on the list. If there are X consecutive 2s, then it should appear only one element in the inside tuple containing X, just like this:

```
[[1, 2, 2, 1],
 [2, 1, 1, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 2]]
```

Gives

```
((1,), (1,), (1, 1),(2,))
```

While

```
[[2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 1, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 1, 2]]
```

Gives

```
((3,),(1, 1),(2,)(3,))
```

> What about the same thing but not for the columns, this time, for the rows? is there a "one-line" method to do it? I mean:

```
[[1, 2, 2, 1],
 [2, 1, 1, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 2]]
```

Gives

```
((2,), (1, 1), (2,))
```

While

```
[[2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 1, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 1, 2]]
```

Gives

```
((4,),(1, 2),(2, 1))
```

I have tried some things, this is one of the things, I can't finish it, don't know what to do anymore, after it:

```
l = [[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2]]
t = (((1,1),(2,),(2,)),((2,),(2,),(1,1)))

if [x.count(0) for x in l] == [0 for x in l]:
        espf = []*len(l)
        espf2 = []
        espf_atual = 0
        contador = 0
        for x in l:
            for c in x:
                celula = x[c]
                if celula == 2:
                    espf_atual += 1
                else:
                    if celula == 1:
                        espf[contador] = [espf_atual]
                        contador += 1
                        espf_atual = 0
        espf2 += [espf_atual]
        espf_atual = 0
    print(tuple(espf2))
```

output
    (3, 3, 3)

this output is the correct one but if I change the list(l) it doesn't work

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? We are not here to code it for you, we are here to help you code it.

Comment: just wrote what you asked

Comment: Thx. Now from here, your first `if` ensures that you don't have any 0 in the list. Is this a requirement? If you put any `0` in the list it will fail. Second, it will only work for the rows that are all `2`. This is because you are storing (properly) intermediate results in `espf[contador]`, but you are not doing anything with it later. You are only using the last occurrences of `2` by only using `espf_actual`.

Comment: yes, I forgot to mention, but is not important, that I don't want any 0 in the lists. But I dont know how to do from here on.. but I guess I should use the espf .. forgot

Comment: seems like espf[contador] has nothing stored.. I don't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have som emistakes in the code.

1. Indexing:

   ```
   for c in x:
       celula = x[c]
   ```

   It should be `celula = c` as `c` already points to each element of `x`.
2. Intermediate results

   For each column you store intermediate results as:

   ```
   espf_atual = 0
   ...
   espf_atual += 1
   ...
   espf2 += [espf_atual]
   ```

   but this will only allow to store the last occurrences of `2` for each column. This is, if a row is `[2,1,2,2]`, then `espf_actual = 2` and you will store only the last occurrence. You will override the first occurrence (before the `1`).

   To avoid this, you need to store intermediate results for each row. You got it halfway with `espf = []*len(l)`, but you never used it properly later.

Find bellow a working example (not too different from your initial solution):

```
espf = []

for x in l:
    # Restart counters for every row
    espf_current = [] # Will store any sequences of 2
    contador = 0      # Will count consecutive 2's

    for c in x:
        celula = c
        if celula == 2:
            contador += 1    # Count number of 2
        elif celula == 1:
            if contador > 0: # Store any 2 before 1
                espf_current += [contador]
            contador = 0
    if contador > 0:         # Check if the row ends in 2
        espf_current += [contador]

    # Store results of this row in the final results
    espf += [tuple(espf_current)]
print tuple(espf)
```

---

The key to switch rows and columns, is to change the indexing method. Currently you are iterating along the elements of the list, and thus, this doesn't allow you to switch between rows and columns.

Another way to see the iteration is to iterate indexes of the matrix (`i, j` for rows and columns) as follows:

```
numRows = len(l)
numCols = len(l[0])

for i in range(numRows):
    for j in range(numCols):
        celula = l[i][j]
```

The above is the indexing equivalent to the previous code. It assumes all the rows have the same length (which is true in your examples). Changing it from rows to columns is straightforward (tip: switch the loops), I leave it to you :P

Comment: so thats for the rows, what about the collumns? where should I change something? I need another for cycle right?

Comment: @Pevides I update the post with some tips. Hope it helps!